# What is a netmask that matches exactly one ip?

Tags: heroku, static-ip-address, netmask, proximo

I'm using [proximo](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/proximo) static ip to connect to a backend service. The [example docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo#forwarding-traffic-through-proximo) show a netmask `172.18.32.0/24`. To my understanding of CIDR that would proxy for `172.18.32.1`, `172.18.32.2`, etc.

I want to use a netmask that only matches one ip address. Is there such a netmask? What would it look like for ip address `5.5.5.5` for example?

I tried without any `/x` entry, but it's not connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mask of `/32` will match exactly one IP.